# Regex capture only 0 to 85

Tags: python, regex

I want to substitute numbers from 0-85. Right now i have 0-89. 
    subject = re.sub(r'([0-8]\w%?)', '', subjectext)

When I do subject = re.sub(r'([0-8][0-5]%?)', '', subjectext)
The regex breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a pattern like this:

```
[1-7]?[0-9]|8[0-5]
```

This will match any string consisting of an optional digit from 1 to 7 followed by a digit from 0 to 9 *or* an 8 followed by a digit from 0 to 5.

If you need to include an optional `%` sign (which wasn't explicitly stated as a requirement, but your pattern seems to suggest that you might need it) use this:

```
([1-7]?[0-9]|8[0-5])%?
```

However, the above will match a string like `9` inside a larger string like `92`. If you don't want this, you might want to consider using lookarounds to make sure that the matched substring isn't preceded by or followed by another digit, like this:

```
(?<!\d)([1-7]?[0-9]|8[0-5])%?(?!\d)
```

Comment: Careful here: `re.sub(r'([1-7]?[0-9]|8[0-5])', 'x', "79 80 89")` has 5 matches 79, 8, 0, 8, 9. With the trailing % it may work.

Comment: This will get it done too, shorter and easier: `\b([1-7]?[0-9]|8[0-5])\b`

Comment: @janos I had considered that, but then it wouldn't match `"foo32"`. It's not clear from the question if that's a valid case, but it's worth considering.

Comment: this might be obvious, but why do we have to separate out 0-79 and then 80-85?

Comment: @user3314418 Regular expressions are about characters, not numeric values. Because the second character in 0-79 and 80-85 has a different range, you need to use a separate character class.

Answer (score 1):

How about this regex?

```
[1-7]?\d|8[0-5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get every number from 0 to 85, so every number start by 0-7 followed by 0-9 or 8 followed by 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5:

```
[1-7]?[0-9]|8[0-5]
# ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
  0 to 79  | 80 to 85
```

Comment: Maxime: I think you'll like the re.VERBOSE flag: http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/verbose.html

Comment: @bukzor I know it, but since I wasn't really using the re module here, I didn't want to explode the regex in pieces :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following Regex...

```
([0-7][0-9]|8[0-5])
```

Good Luck!